# How to prevent an HTML form from being submitted if the conditions went false?

Tags: jquery, forms, razor

I have a simple `@Html.BeginForm()` with some hidden fields just as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductID }))
 {
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedQuantity, new { @id = "selectedquantity" })
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AvailableColors, new { @id = "selectedcolor" })
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSizes, new { @id = "selectedsize"})
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
   @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)

   <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to cart" />
 }
```

I want to prevent form from submitting when the hidden field values are null, is that possible? If yes how?
The hidden field values are update by this below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#quantity").on("change", function () {
            var quantity = $(this).val();
            $("#selectedquantity").val(quantity).val();
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#selectable").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.selected).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
                $("#selectedsize").val($("#selectable>li.ui-selected").html());
            }
        });

        $("#selectable1").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ci) {
                $(ci.selected).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
                $("#selectedcolor").val($("#selectable1>li.ui-selected").html());
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add "onsubmit" in your form;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductID, onsubmit = "validateForm()" }))
```

And then declare the function `validateForm` like:

```
function validateForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($("#selectedquantity").val() === '' || $("#selectedcolor").val() === '' || $("#selectedsize").val() === '') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

More generally, anytime your validation function return `false`, then your form would not be submitted.

Comment: I did it this way but it is still submitting the form!

Comment: is the function validateForm invoked?

Comment: How do i check that? Debug?

Comment: Yes use the debugger or just console.log to make sure it's called.

Comment: When i check that please take a look on update question.

Comment: No it is not invoked when i press the submit button but there are some other jquery script which is invoked and works perfectly? couldn't be the problem of jquery loaded or not.

Comment: That function uses jQuery only for selecting inputs so if it's not invoked it's not a matter jQuery loaded or not (in that case you would have errors but the function will be called in any case)...

Comment: What do you advise then?